# Show that there exist a choice function on the power set of the natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to show that there exist a choice function on the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ (without using the Axiom of Choice). So I know that you can define a choice function on $\mathbb{N}$ by simply taking the smallest element, but I dont't really know how to define a proper choice function on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: A choice function on a set (of sets)  $A$ is a map $f\colon A\to \bigcup A$ such that $f(a)\in a$ for all $a\in A$. If $\emptyset\in A$, a choice function cannot exist.

Comment: Are you trying to choose a set of naturals from any nonempty set of such sets? I'd describe that as a choice function on $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N))\setminus\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Unfortunately the terminology is a bit unstandardized here. Is the function you mention that maps a nonempty set of naturals to its least element considered a choice function on $\mathbb N$, a choice function on $P(\mathbb N)-\{\varnothing\}$, or, worst of all, a choice function on $P(\mathbb N)$? In any event, it’s probably the one you’re looking for: you need AC to obtain a function that takes each nonempty subset of $P(\mathbb N)$ to one of its elements.